# Accounting for large absolute differences between entities in panel data regression

Tags: multiple-regression, panel-data, count-data

I want to estimate the effect of weather on business success by using a a panel data regression.
My dependent variable is the daily number of visitors for different entities (for example amusement parks) over a few years. The relevant independent variables are some weather variables (for example rainfall on the respective day in the respective region).
My problem is that the entities in the panel are very different in terms of absolute size. There are entities with almost 20 Mio. visitors in a good year and other entities with only 2 Mio. Visitors in a good year. Therefore I would guess, that if I use the absolute number of daily visitors as dependent variable, my results are not very meaningful, as the coeffizients will overestimate the effect of weather for small entities and underestimate the effect of weather for large entities.
What is the right way to solve this issue? Does it make sense to standardize the data in some way?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have repeat observations for each attraction, you can use a multilevel model with "site" as a random (or level 1) variable and weather variables as fixed (or level 2) variables.

These are somewhat complex to fit, but they can be thought of as a sort of generalization of paired t-tests.

There are lots of threads about MLMs here, and also many books and sites.

Comment: thanks for your answer!
However, I was actually hoping for an easier solution, that allows me to still use the standard fixed effects regression.
What is the problem, if I just standardize the daily values by using the respective mean and standard deviation of each entity? Will I get tremendously biased result when following this approach?

Comment: If you do that you are throwing away tons of information, increasing type I and II error rates and making it impossible to answer some key questions. This is well covered in various books. I like the explanation in the first chapter of Hedeker and Gibbons "Longitudinal Data Analysis".